# SQL SSMS Server Job - Can it calculate random values?

Tags: sql, scheduled-tasks, ssms, jobs

I'm very new to this side of SQL and SSMS so I apologize if this is an easy question.
I've been going through some tutorials and I think I understand how to schedule and create a job, but I'm not sure how it would work for my particular circumstance:

I need to:

- Get All the rows from one table `[TRAINER table]`
- for each of these rows,
- - Calculate a value based on that row's `[AverageSteps]` field, multiplied by a random double between 0.85 and 1.15
- - Add a new row in the `[TRAINER_SYNC] table` with the random value from above, the row's `[TrainerId]` field, and the `current DateTime`

Is this possible? 
I'm not quite sure how to loop through the rows (if it's even possible), and then how to get a random number.

Would anyone know if this is possible, or any alternatives if it isn't, or any tutorials I could follow?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's generally a bad idea to loop through rows manually as cursors are not optimised. Apply a set operation instead.

Use `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` to obtain your rows and then insert into the sync table.

Create this as a Transact-SQL Job Step:

```
INSERT INTO trainer_sync (AverageSteps, TrainerId, Time)
SELECT AverageSteps * (RAND()*(1.15-0.85)+0.85), TrainerId, GETDATE()
FROM trainer;
```

Note `rand()` creates a decimal, not a double. If you need the *output* to be a double, you'll need to `CAST` it. See [this documentation](https://www.techonthenet.com/sql_server/functions/rand.php).

[Here's a guide](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188263(v=sql.105).aspx) to the INSERT ... SELECT from MS.

Comment: thanks - that should be enough to get me going. Thanks a bunch!